# WinForms - Overlapping two controls in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` containing 5 rows and 5 columns with variable sizes (a 3x3 grid with filler cells on the sides). In each of the inner cells, I put a `PictureBox` with the `Dock` parameter set on `Fill`. I now want to add a `Label` that would cover the entirety of those 9 cells. Since the `Label` is transparent and not always visible, there should be no issues with this.

But when I try to move the `Label` in the `TableLayoutPanel`, all it does is "compress" the `PictureBoxes` on the bottom or on the right.

Here is a before/after set of pictures :

[image: Before]

[image: After]
(the text in white is a part of the program, not a caption)

I have tried modifying the `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` properties of the label, but to no avail. As of now the `Dock` properties of the `PictureBoxes` is set on `Fill`, and so is the `Label`. Setting it to `None` only makes it smaller, but leaves the `PictureBoxes` stacked at the bottom.

I have also tried modifying the `TabIndexes` but had no luck with this either.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: You can not put more than one control into cell of `TableLayoutPanel`. What you can is to put `Label` and `TableLayoutPanel` into same container (e.g. `Panel`). In addition you have to make `Label` size related on `TableLayoutPanel` child size (if I understood layout correctly). For this you can manually handle `Resized` event of that child

Comment: Set `PictureBox` as `Label` parent. I.e. `pictureBox.Controls.Add(label)`.

Comment: Putting the `Label` and `TableLayoutPanel` into the same `Panel` fixed it, thank you! You might want to post it so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, as [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) pointed out, is to create a container like a `Panel` and make it contain both overlapping controls (here, the `PictureBox` and the `TableLayoutPanel` containing the 9 other `PictureBoxes`), since a `TableLayoutPanel` can only contain one element per cell.

The structure of the document must look like this:

```
Form
↳ Panel
  ↳ PictureBox        # The big one
  ↳ TableLayoutPanel
    ↳ PictureBox      # The 9 small ones
      ...
    ↳ PictureBox
```